# magento links not working properly while redirecting from product info page to other cms pages

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, magento-1.9.2.0

I am using magento 1.9.2 for my website.

My website address is `127.0.0.1/magento`. Before it was adding `index.php` while visiting any cms pages for example `127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/about-us`

so I have made changes like shown in this [tutorial](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-remove-index-php-from-the-website-url.html#prettyPhoto)

Now its working fine with all cms pages but product category pages and product page `127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/My-category.html` for category page
and `127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/my-category/my-product.html` for product page

now when I try to redirect from `127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/my-category/my-product` this link to any cms page It shows link `127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/my-category/about-us` like this...

what will be the problem

my screenshot of `system->configuration->general->web`

[image]

Comment: please show your about-us link from footer or static block?

Comment: @Rakesh Sorry, didn't get you

Comment: please show your about us link code in magento? Whether you have set link for this

Comment: Actually I haven't code for this. I dont have links in footer for any of cms page. I am using Megamenu plugin and added about-us cms page in it

Comment: Show screenshot of url rewrite